# Vim colorscheme not displaying properly

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, linux-mint, colors

I realize that questions about Vim colorschemes have been asked quite frequently, but I believe I've tried the advice in all of them and I can't quite seem to get my colorschemes to work. That being said, my question is as follows:

How do I get Vim (when run from Linux Mint (Ubuntu Version) 17 default terminal) to display the proper colorscheme of my choosing? Currently, when using a colorscheme such as Twilight, I should be seeing something like this (picture taken in Sublime):

[image: Sublime]

However, I'm seeing this, running in the default Mint terminal:

[image: Vim]

I've tried to modify my .vimrc to have `set t_Co=256`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Additionally, my `$TERM` is also set to `xterm-256color`, as has been suggested. Neither of those things seem to be making a difference. Does anyone know where else I could be making a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: From @nlu: Looks to me as if your language is not recognized. What happens if you force the language for the syntax with:  :setf C  ?

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem by adding this to my ~/.vimrc file:

```
set t_Co=256
```

But if that doesn't work you can also try adding these two lines too:

```
let &t_AB="\e[48;5;%dm"
let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"
```

Comment: Please make sure you read the question carefully when answering, as it specifically mentions that trying this didn't work.